# Why did the captive aliens in Independence Day II (Resurgence) have their body armor?

Tags: independence-day, independence-day-resurgence

Why did the captive aliens in Independence Day II (Resurgence) still have their body armor?

Comment: You mean the ones in the holding cells? I guess when they escaped and attacked they were in full gear...
I've only seen the movie once, and that was a quick scene showing them in their cells, are you sure they had full armor? Perhaps if not, when they escaped they found and put on their old armor?

Comment: @Garrettfromhp They did. And as far as I saw it was unexplained.

Comment: @Garrettfromhp Yea but before they escaped too, because there was the part where the former president let one out of its cell and the African warlord had to kill it and that one had armor too.

Comment: My best guess is that the aliens read the movie script and saw the need for the extra plot suspense.  XD

Comment: @Garrettfromhp - I must have missed the suspenseful part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The film's official novelisation offers a potential reason.

### To help keep them alive (for future interrogation)

Although the aliens can *adapt* to Earth-like conditions, they apparently have an annoying tendency to die without warning. Keeping them in their exosuits may simply be a way of prolonging their lives.

> *This entire building had been designed to house the aliens and keep them alive so they could be studied. **What little was known—or could be inferred—about their preferred habitat had been incorporated into the design. Not to keep them comfortable, but to extend their lives and therefore the opportunity to study them.***
>
> *They seemed able to adapt to the terrestrial atmosphere and temperatures. As a result, some scientific personnel theorized that Earth-like conditions were necessary for advanced life forms to exist anywhere in the universe. Adams didn’t think the sample size was all that convincing.*